# How to call onListItemClick if we are also using onTouchListener in ListView in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gesture

When I add `ontouchListener` in my `listview` the `onListItemClick` is not working.

I want to use `OnTouchListener` for fling and `onListItemClick` for single click in the listview because I'm using the position from onListItemClick to create new activity and ontouch for fling swipe gesture.

```
public class FRAG1 extends ListFragment {

    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_PATH = "AAA-1";
    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_TITLE = "AAA-2";
    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_ARTIST = "AAA-3";
    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_DURATION = "AAA-4";
    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_ID = "AAA-5";

    private static final Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    private static final String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION };
    private static final String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED;

    /* THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND */
    private static final String[] from = { MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION };

    /* THE XML DEFINED VIEWS WHICH THE DATA WILL BE BOUND TO */
    private static final int[] to = { R.id.list_Title, R.id.list_Artist,
            R.id.list_Duration };

    private static Cursor videoCursor;
    private static int videoPathColumnIndex;
    private static int videoTitleColumnIndex;
    private static int videoArtistColumnIndex;
    private static int videoDurationColumnIndex;
    private static int videoIdColumnIndex;

    private static String videoPath;
    private static String videoTitle;
    private static String videoArtist;
    private static int videoDuration;
    private static int videoId;

    /* GET THE CONTEXT OF LISTFRAGMENT FROM HOMEPAGE ACTIVITY */
    Context context;

    /* TO LUNCH 2nd CLASS AND PUT MEDIA INFO INTO */
    private static Intent vIntent;

    /* MY CUSTOM ADAPTER */
    private static MyCustomSimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    /* GESTUREDETOR FOR COMPATIBILITY */
    GestureDetectorCompat detector;

    /* MY LISTVIEW */
    ListView lv;

    /* CUSTOM TYPE INFLATION IF NEED TO ADD MORE VIEW IN LISTVIEW XML LAYOUT */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_this_week, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        context = getActivity();

        // CREATE CURSOR THAT WILL HOLD ALL VALUE
        videoCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(sourceUri, projection,
                null, null, orderBy);

        // CREATE THE ADAPTER USING THE CURSOR POINTING TO THE
        // DESIRED DATA AS WELL AS THE LAYOUT INFORMATION
        adapter = new MyCustomSimpleCursorAdapter(context,
                R.layout.list_row_items, videoCursor, from, to);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // GET THE INSTANCE OF LISTVIEW FOR THE SWIPEVIEW PURPOSE
        lv = getListView();

        detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context,
                new MyOnSwipeTouchListener());

        lv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("true");
                return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // MOVE TO CLICK POSITION
                if (videoCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                    // GET THE COLUMN INDEX OF THE FILEPATH, TITLE, ARTIST,
                    // DURATION
                    videoPathColumnIndex = videoCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                    videoTitleColumnIndex = videoCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
                    videoArtistColumnIndex = videoCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST);
                    videoDurationColumnIndex = videoCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
                    videoIdColumnIndex = videoCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);

                    // LIST THE DATA OF THE COLUMNINDEX OF THE VIDEOCURSOR
                    // POSITION
                    videoPath = videoCursor.getString(videoPathColumnIndex);
                    videoTitle = videoCursor.getString(videoTitleColumnIndex);
                    videoArtist = videoCursor.getString(videoArtistColumnIndex);
                    videoDuration = videoCursor
                            .getInt(videoDurationColumnIndex);
                    videoId = videoCursor.getInt(videoIdColumnIndex);

                    // START THE NEW INTENT ACTIVITY AND PASS SOME MEDIA INFO
                    vIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Play.class);

                    vIntent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_PATH, videoPath);
                    vIntent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_TITLE, videoTitle);
                    vIntent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_ARTIST, videoArtist);
                    vIntent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_DURATION, videoDuration);
                    vIntent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_ID, videoId);

                    startActivity(vIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /** NESTED CLASS FOR MY CUSTOM SWIPE TOUCH LISTENER */
    public class MyOnSwipeTouchListener extends
            GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "on fling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my custom cursor adapter

```
/* CUSTOM ADAPTER FOR TABTHISWEEK */
public class MyCustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private static int layout;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;
    private MyViewHolder holder;

    public MyCustomSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout,
            Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, 0);

        MyCustomSimpleCursorAdapter.layout = layout;
        MyCustomSimpleCursorAdapter.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        holder = (MyViewHolder) view.getTag();

        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new MyViewHolder();

            holder.titleHolder = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_Title);
            holder.artistHolder = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_Artist);
            holder.durationHolder = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_Duration);
            holder.imageHolder = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_Image);
            holder.playHolder = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.list_Play);


            view.setTag(holder);
        }



        /*
         * GET THE COLUMN INDEX OF TITLE, ARTIST, DURATION AND
         * THE ROWID OF THE VIDEO IMAGE THUMBNAIL PER LOOP
         */
        holder.titleIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
        holder.artistIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST);
        holder.durationIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
        holder.imageIndex = cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

        /* SET THE TITLE BUT IF NULL SET TO DEFAULT FROM RESOURCES */
        try {
            holder.titleHolder.setText(cursor.getString(holder.titleIndex));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("XXXXXX" + e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
            holder.titleHolder.setText(context.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.list_view_default_text_title));
        }

        /* SET THE ARTIST BUT IF NULL SET TO DEFAULT FROM RESOURCES */
        try {
            holder.artistHolder.setText(cursor.getString(holder.artistIndex));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("XXXXXX" + e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
            holder.artistHolder.setText(context.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.list_view_default_text_artist));
        }

        /* SET THE TIME DURATION IF NULL SET TO DEFAULT */
        try {
            holder.milliseconds = Integer.parseInt(cursor
                    .getString(holder.durationIndex));

            holder.seconds = holder.milliseconds / 1000;
            holder.minutes = holder.seconds / 60;
            holder.seconds = holder.seconds % 60;
            holder.minutes = holder.minutes % 60;

            holder.durationHolder.setText(String.format("%2d:%02d",
                    holder.minutes, holder.seconds));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("XXXXXX" + e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
            holder.durationHolder.setText(context.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.list_view_default_text_duration));
        }

        /* SET THE BITMAP IMAGE FOR THE IMAGEVIEW */
        try {
            holder.options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            holder.options.inDither = false;
            holder.options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            holder.bitmapVidThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    context.getContentResolver(), holder.imageIndex,
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            holder.imageHolder.setImageBitmap(holder.bitmapVidThumb);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("XXXXXX" + e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
            holder.imageHolder.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.default_img));
        }

        /* SET DEFAULT VALUE IF TITLE IS NULL */
        if (holder.titleHolder.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            holder.titleHolder.setText(context.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.list_view_default_text_title));
        }

        /* SET DEFAULT VALUE IF ARTIST IS NULL */
        if (holder.artistHolder.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            holder.artistHolder.setText(context.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.list_view_default_text_artist));
        }
    }

    /* MY NESTED VIEW HOLDER CLASS */
    static class MyViewHolder {
        BitmapFactory.Options options;
        Bitmap bitmapVidThumb;

        ImageButton playHolder;

        ImageView imageHolder;
        TextView titleHolder;
        TextView artistHolder;
        TextView durationHolder;

        Integer milliseconds;
        Integer seconds;
        Integer minutes;

        int imageIndex;
        int titleIndex;
        int artistIndex;
        int durationIndex;

        int durationTemp;
    }
}
```

updated my codes for more info about my question

Comment: I had also the same problem like you.Because of ontouchlistener onlistitemclick not works dont know why..You should use custom adapter.

Comment: did u solve the problem already Kailash?

Comment: yes.I did before by using custom adapter

Comment: tnx kailash for the advice!

Comment: You just do what i say bro i guide you.

Comment: ok bro ill add my customcursoradapter then you edit my codes

Comment: bro i have already aded my adapter can you edit my codes

Answer (score 0):

well your problem isnt really with what you are thinking , you need to overrider

setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemCLickListener) method of the ListView class insted of onListItemClick , and use it with setOnTouchListener youll get the results perfectly , hers an example code showing the two methods in action .

```
ListView list = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
    list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String [] men = { "RJ" ,"DJ ", " Snoop " , " Doogy " ," Doggg" , "2 pac"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,men);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hello");

            return false;
        }
    });

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(arg2);

    }
});
```

Lemme know if its what you were looking for

Comment: bro i put toast in the onitemclick and toast also in ontouch but in ontouch its always repating the toast after i click or fling it, why the ontouch keep repeating to call even in one click only?

Comment: U mean to say you put toast message in my above code and still only one of them is responding??

Comment: the onclick and ontouch is already running but when i put some toast to see how many times it will be called then i found out during ontuch

lv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("true");
                return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

it called many times so toast are appearing many times

Comment: well as you would be aware that toast is not a fast command and it creates these kinda ambiguity in scenarios like such . better make use of Log.d("tag","message") to cross check and lemme know what’s the result